# Daily average pay

Tags: self-learning, average

Imagine we have the following situation:

Worker 1: worked days: 20; total $ earned: 200; \$/day: 10\$/day

Worker 2: worked days: 30; total $ earned: 200; \$/day: 6.7\$/day

The average pay per day of the two workers is then 8.3\$/day,
however on a website I found the following computation: 400\$/50days=8\$/day. Is it possible to reason in the latter way e.g. when we only have the totals and not each worker's daily average?

Thank u for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the average is a value that, substituted in the original data, ceteris paribus gives the same amount of expense, thus

$$20\times m+30\times m=200+200$$

that is

$$m=\frac{400}{50}=8$$

---

If you use your value you get that the total amount of expense is

$$20\times8.3+30\times8.3=415\ne400$$

thus your calculation is wrong.

A question... how did you get 8.3? doing an arithmetical mean you get $\frac{10+6.7}{2}=8.35$

Comment: And what is wrong with the first computation?

Comment: @Anna:  see my edits

Comment: It came out 8.3 because I didn't round any decimals from the beginning on